# Django Admin - No se muestran todos los campos del modelo cuando se añaden entradas

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Estaba siguiendo el tutorial pero creando nuevos modelos para mi aplicación. Cuando añado los modelos al panel de admin e intento create nuevas entradas no puedo ver cada uno de los campos del modelo.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import datetime


class Plataformas(models.Model):
    class ModosPago(models.TextChoices):
        m = 'M', 'Mensual'
        a = 'A', 'Anual'

    nombre = models.TextField(verbose_name='Nombre Plataforma'),
    precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Precio'),
    modopa = models.CharField(choices=ModosPago.choices, max_length=1, verbose_name='Modo de pago')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nombre)


class Pagadores(models.Model):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
    nombre = models.TextField(max_length=60, help_text='Nombre usuario'),
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Plataformas, on_delete=models.CASCADE, help_text='Plataforma')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.usuario)


class Pagos(models.Model):
    idpago = models.AutoField(),
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(Pagadores, to_field='usuario', help_text='Usuario', on_delete=models.CASCADE),
    fechapago = models.DateField('Fecha de Pago', default=datetime.date.today()),
    yearpago = models.DateField('Año del Pago', default=datetime.date.year),
    mespago = models.DateField('Mes del Pago', default=datetime.date.month),
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Pagadores, to_field='platform', help_text='Plataforma', on_delete=models.CASCADE),
    importe = models.DecimalField(help_text='Importe del pago', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.idpago)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Pagos, Plataformas, Pagadores

admin.site.register(Plataformas)
admin.site.register(Pagadores)
admin.site.register(Pagos)
```

admin site
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay algo que esté haciendo mal? He comprobado la documentación y buscado por internet pero no he podido encontrar solución al problema.

**EDIT: El problema eran las comas al final de cada campo del modelo y ciertos atributos de estos campos en el modelo, esto provocaba que no se me generarán todos los campos en Base de datos.**

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Change the Spanish language so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tu idioma nativo es el español, así que te escribiré así:

Tienes que declarar una clase por cada modelo:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Pagos, Plataformas, Pagadores

class PagosAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('usuario', 'fechapago', <y todos los campos que quieras>)

class PlataformasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nombre', 'precio', 'modopa')

admin.site.register(Plataformas, PlataformasAdmin)
admin.site.register(Pagos, PagosAdmin)
```

Esta es otra forma de hacerlo, te pondré mis propios ejemplos y adapta al tuyo:

```
from core.inv.models import Product

@admin.register(Product) 
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
fields = ('code', 'barcode', 'name', 'description', 'slug', 
'product_type', 'category', 'model', 'brand', 'cost', 'fact', 'price', 
'image', 'is_inventoried', 'active', 'store', 'special_offers', 
'featured_products', 'best_seller', 'is_hot')
list_display_links = ('name', 'model')
list_display = ('name', 'model', 'marca', 'store', 'brand', 'category', 
'active', 'catalogue', 'special_offers', 'featured_products', 
'best_seller', 'is_hot', 'created_at')
list_editable = ('active', 'catalogue', 'brand', 'category', 'store', 
'special_offers', 'featured_products', 'best_seller', 'is_hot')
search_fields = ['code', 'name']
list_per_page = 15
```

Comment: Buenas, he realizado esa misma prueba y el resultado sigue siendo el mismo, parece como si no llegara a cargar correctamente algo dentro del modelo con respecto al admin.

Comment: 1- Si sabes que su idioma nativo es español por que no le recomendaste editar su pregunta?
2- Para que creas clases `PagosAdmin` y `PlataformasAdmin` si lo pasa al metodo register `admin.site.register(Plataformas, PlataformasAdmin)` y `admin.site.register(Pagos, PagosAdmin)`

Comment: Ya estaria traducido.

Comment: Disculpa Arleal, te confundí un poco por estar en apuros. Voy a editar mi respuesta.